# Angular 2 Dynamic Page Header and Footer

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

The following is what is included in my app.component.html

`<lmenu></lmenu>
<header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>`

However my login and register pages are both rendered through this module and they only require the router-outlet. How an dynamically not include the lmenu, header, and footer selectors for the login and register views? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<lmenu *ngIf="isLogin"></lmenu>
<header *ngIf="isLogin"></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer *ngIf="isLogin"></footer>
```

Just switching `isLogin` between `true` and `false` shows/hides the components

Comment: Ah I see.... Sorry new to angular Structural Directives are what I was missing, thank you! https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Answer (score 1):

```
you could use two times in the terminal: 
- ng generate component header
- ng generate component footer

then, in the main app file HTML (app.component.html) you must include the 2 tags: 
<app-header></app-header>
<app-footer></app-footer>

this is the first thing to do.

Then you must populate your templates:
- header.component.html and the styling in header.component.css
- footer.component.html and the styling in footer.component.css
```