# Angular 4 - What is the standard way to implement the theme or template

Tags: angular

I am a newbie in Angular, I want to create pages for admin panel like, Sign-in, Sign-up, Dashboard and pages with sidebar (with different page layout), I use routing to navigate the pages. How can I separately design templates and use them according to my need, also tell the right way to call the external scripts/css for different templates.

Thanks.

Comment: https://material.angular.io

Comment: AKVEO is one admin panel you can learn from. https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin - p.s go with Angular 5

Comment: I got the answer from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492687/angular-2-dynamic-page-header-and-footer?rq=1